# Sending data from Activity to Fragment with Interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I am developng an app and I've added image below to demonstrate my issue. When i click star button on the main activity, Second Activity opens. In the Second Activity i have listview and when i click the listview items, i want to send value from second activity to Fragment. I am able to do this stuff between  two fragments with interface but i am not able to do this issue with interface. When i declare interface at Second Activity, I get CastExxcceptionError.

How can i do this ? I also tried bundle but it is take me error too.

I dont know how to do ?

Thanks in advance for sharing experiences.

PS: I added codes below. 1st step is working wonderfully. Only 2nd step is not working as i want

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = new FragmentActivity();
FragmentActivity newFragment;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    al.add("District");
    al.add("Parcel");
    al.add("Satellite");
    al.add("Mosaic");
    al.add("Hybrid");
    al.add("Building");
    al.add("Road");
    al.add("Door");
    al.add("Cat");
    al.add("Dog");
    al.add("Bird");
    al.add("Weather");
    al.add("Heaven");
    al.add("Paradise");
    al.add("Super");
    al.add("Wonderful");
    al.add("Great");
    al.add("Thanks");
    al.add("For");
    al.add("Helpings");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         fragmentActivity.Response(al.get(position));

        }
    });


}
```

}

**FragmentActivity**

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container,false);
    return v;

}
public void Response(String data){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: @IntegralOfTan `fragmentActivity.Response(al.get(position));`  at `SecondActivity` this line give me error.

Comment: try replacing getActivity() with getActivity.getApplicationContext()

Comment: gives me nullpointerexception error. same line.

Comment: run your code in debugging mode to find out which variable is null

Comment: I think my usage is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an activity just to create (and display) a list of elements. Can't you just use a `DialogFragment` for this purpose?

This way, it's easy to make the transition and get the result back. A full example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Joev-/5695813) (not tested, but I think you can easily find this kind of resource on the Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Call you 2nd Activity from the 1st using `startActivityForResult`.

In 2nd Activity in `onListItemClick` create `Intent` containing the data you need as `extras` and call `setResult` passing that `Intent` as an argument, and `finish()` the 2nd Activity.

In 1st activity you will get this Intent in `OnActivityResult` then.

Comment: Thanks for comment @Alex, Can i use startactivityforresult inside onoptionsmenuitemclick or button click ?

Comment: Sure you can, from everywhere inside Activity or Fragment. However,if from inner class, then use YourActivity.this not simply this.

Comment: When i try to add startActivityForResult inside button it can not be resolved.